# Scripts and CSS file don't load for virtual application (asp.net 5)

Tags: c#, css, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET 5 application installed in IIS as a virtual application under the Default Web Site. This application's virtual path we will say is '/MyVirtualApp'. I have modified the route on one of the application's controller so that the route is:

```
[Route("MyVirtualApp/[controller]")]
```

The controller and its actions respond to requests such as this:

```
http://localhost/MyVirtualApp/MyController/MyAction/
```

The problem is that the scripts and css added in my "_Layout.cshtml" do not respect the virtual application path. Those files are trying to load like this:

```
http://localhost/css/site.css
```

The code in the _Layout.cshtml file is as follows for the referenced css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

From what I understand this should produce a relative path, but it is only relative to the default site, not the virtual application.

**How do I load my javascript and css files so that they reference the virtual application path?**

Answer (score 0):

Your application still remains in the same base application path `http://localhost`, and by using `[Route()]` you are only modifying the routes. There is, however, a problem with the `httpPlatformHandler` regarding virtual applications/directories. This has been fixed and set to release with RC2.

The current workaround is:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
     app.Map("/MyVirtualApp", map => ConfigureMyVirtualApp(map, env, loggerFactory));
 }

 public void ConfigureMyVirtualApp(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
     loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Information;
     loggerFactory.AddConsole();
     loggerFactory.AddDebug();

     // Add the platform handler to the request pipeline.
     app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

     app.UseDefaultFiles();
     // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
     app.UseStaticFiles();
 }
```

If that doesn't work, make sure your virtual application paths are properly setup in **applicationhost.config**. In asp.net core there is one in the `.vs\config` folder in your project source for IIS Express, and in `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\IISExpress\config` for IIS.

I hope that helps.